# Looking to create a daily average calculation in tableau where the number of appointment dates are fixed

Tags: calculation, tableau-desktop

To get daily average, we use the (number of visits)/(number of business days). Here is my issue, visits(numerator) can occur on weekends days however, we want our denominator (business days) to be a fixed number in which it doesn't include weekends or holidays(but keep visits that occur on weekends).
So I cannot simply just filter out dates without losing visits that occur on weekends, and if I include weekends then it skews our number of business days. Is there anything I can do to ONLY count the number of business days limited to Monday through Friday & no weekends (for the denominator), without filtering dates (so that it does not affect the numerator)?
I tried creating a "Business Day" field, but not sure how this could be used in the calculation again without it being filter.

My attempt below, figured if I could create a calculated field then I could just divide below by number of visits

IE.
IF  [Business Day] = 'Business Day'
THEN COUNT([VISIT])
END
Error Message: Cannot Mix aggregate and non aggregate comparisons or results in If Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Believe the issue is that you're trying to mix aggregated/non-aggregated fields in the same calc (comparing # of visits aggregation in the if statement against a non-aggregated [Business Day]). What you can try is creating 3 Calculated Fields for the result you're after. You might have to play around with it

**Number # of visits**

```
[Number of Visits] = COUNT([VISIT])
```

**Number of Business Days**: excluding Sun[1] & Sat[7]

```
[Number of Business Days] = 
SUM(
    CASE DATEPART('weekday', [Date])
        WHEN 1 THEN 0
        WHEN 7 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END
)
```

To get your **Average Number of Visits per Business Day**

```
[Average Visits per Business Day] = [Number of Visits] / [Number of Business Days]
```